# Why can't I add more CiviCase fields to my Profile?

Tags: wordpress, profile, civicase

I have created a new Profile to prompt the user to complete a new Case within CiviCase. However, when adding fields to the Profile, it only offers the 'Case Subject' field from CiviCase. What have I missed about the other fields (which are all unmodified, such as the Case Date) that will allow other fields to be added?
David

(4.7.9 on Wordpress, so I can't use Webforms)

Answer (score 1):

(EDITED) When you set up a civicrm profile using lateset civicrm you can add Case fields and they all seem to be available. The below shows Profile with Case Subject and Case Status added and other fields still to add.

[image]

Comment: Oh I may have misunderstood his question. At http://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org I do see "Case" in the list that you have above, and then if you pick it another dropdown appears that has some case-related fields.

Comment: That is weird - I was sure I just grabbed that screenshot from demo. Must be going nuts.

Comment: Have updated with a screenshot off wp demo. I also checked that other Case fields were available after adding Individual fields. Have you added any fields that are not Case or Individual?

Comment: Pete, yes, that's exactly what I'd expected to see. The only fields I've already added to the profile are Case Subject (Case), First Name (Individual) and Last Name (Individual). The Field Name of the dialog 'New Profile Field' now doesn't offer 'Case' as an option any longer. I can't think how to work around this!

Comment: what happens if you start afresh. first add case subject, then can you add case status etc - ie try to replicate what is clearly working on demo site in exact same order

Comment: OK, I tried that: on adding the first field to a brand new profile, the _only_ field offered from 'Case' is 'Case Subject'. The list of fields isn't being built correctly. (I have admin rights.)

Comment: I glanced through the code and don't see anything obvious that might cause this. If you can do debugging then start at CRM/Core/BAO/UFField.php around line 991 where it says $caseFields = CRM_Case_BAO_Query::getFields(TRUE); and put in some debugging output and try and track it down.

Answer (score 1):

We have upgraded to CiviCRM 5.0.1 and, magically, all the missing CiviCase fields became available for selection in the Profile, just as in Pete's screenshot. Thank you for showing how it should look.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I may have misunderstood your question. See my comment below petednz's answer below, but it doesn't help you it just confirms there are more fields visible on the public demo.

It only displays the fields from the profile used for drupal user registration. E.g. the built-in name and address profile.